# How to change an M2M field in a UpdateView?

Tags: python, django

SOLVED by Peter DeGlopper:

Thank you for your help it solved my issues, I really do appreciate it. I was banging my head against the table.

1. I didn't have to change my ModelForm. Looking at the HTML source I noticed in the input tag **checked="checked"** A subnet was being outputted as checked but it wasn't showing checked in my browser. This was in Firefox 24.2.0 in CentOS (On a VM), so I went to my Windows 7 host and loaded up Firefox 26.0 it worked, and worked fine in IE8 as well. That was weird, but it explains your confusion of that it should just work.
2. For saving the fields thanks to you I now see how I was over thinking it. And I am able to update the M2M field. I updated the TagUpdateView below to show the working code.

---

I have 2 issues with trying use an UpdateView with a M2M field...

1. The currently "tagged" subnets dont show up as checked in my template
2. How would I handle updating the M2M relationship in my TagUpdateView by overriding form_valid?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Tag m2m models.py:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    subnet = models.ManyToManyField(Subnet, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tag_created_by')
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tag_modified_by')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag
```

Tag ModelForm:

```
class TagForm(forms.ModelForm):

    subnet = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=True, queryset=Subnet.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        exclude = ('date_created', 'created_by', 'date_modified', 'modified_by')
```

Tag views.py:

```
class TagUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'tag_update.html'
    model = Tag
    form_class = TagForm

    def form_valid(self, form):

        update_tag = form.save(commit=False)

        update_tag.modified_by = self.request.user

        update_tag.save()

        form.save_m2m()

        return super(TagUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

My template "tag_update.html":

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block title %}Tag {{ object.tag }} Update{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Tag {{ object.tag }} Update</h1>
    <br />
    <form action="" method="post" role="form">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_tag">Tag Name</label>
                    {% render_field form.tag placeholder=form.tag.label class="form-control" %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_group">Group</label>
                    {% render_field form.group placeholder=form.group.label class="form-control"%}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_description">Description</label>
                    {% render_field form.description placeholder=form.description.label class="form-control" rows="5" %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_checkbox">Link to Subnets</label>
                     {{ form.subnet }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br />
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking it. Handling this kind of relationship can be a little bit complicated if you need to track information on the relationship model itself (like a modified timestamp for when a particular subnet/tag pair was created) but for the model relationships you've shown here, `form.save_m2m()` is sufficient - it handles the m2m relationship for you.

You wouldn't even need that if you didn't need to use `commit=False` on your initial form save so you can set your `modified_by` field.

For prepopulation - mostly this looks to me like it should follow the normal behavior and prepopulate. I would probably just use the widget class rather than explicitly instantiating it (`widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple` rather than `widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()`) but I don't see why that would affect it.

For both problems, you might have good results by starting with a simple `ModelForm` with no customizations on `subnet`, just `exclude` set. Once that's working, put in the special view code to handle `modified_by`. Once that's working, change to a custom widget declaration for `subnet` - maybe initially using the `meta` widgets override dictionary rather than a custom field declaration for the first pass.