# django update many to many field in update view

Tags: django

I am currently working on a project using Django. Below, I have a model that has manytomany fields.

```
employees = models.ManyToManyField(user_model.EmployeeProfile, blank=True)
```

How to add an object from a related model to that field? I use the update view and override the form_valid function.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()

        employee = user_model.EmployeeProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user.id)
        self.object.employees.add(employee)

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The above code is not working properly. 
I need help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does it mean "its not working"? does it throw error?

Comment: there is no error at all, but the object was not successfully added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change an M2M field in a UpdateView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600043/how-to-change-an-m2m-field-in-a-updateview)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm having the exact same problem.